# Send the text of cell clicked, to the next view

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, segue

1.1, I have a TableView, linked with sqlite, when i click a cell, the program goes to the prepareForSegue, before getting the value inside of tableView didSelectedRow.

For this in the first visit of secondView the value of Label is nil, if i back to the previous view and select other cell, i get the first cell value.

I have a UILabel in the secondView and this text would be the cell selected.

I don´t know how i can say at segue the text value of the tableView.

May be somebody can help me, apologies if my english is bad.

Thanks.

`#import "farmacopeaViewController.h"`

## import "AddFarmacoViewController.h"  //second View`

`@implementation farmacopeaViewController`

`@synthesize copiaFarmaco,farmacos,descript;`

`- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style`
`{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}`

`- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`
{
   // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`

```
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
```

}

`- (void)viewDidLoad`
{
   `[super viewDidLoad];`

`[self populateFarmacos];`
   `[self populateDescrip];`
}

`-(void) populateFarmacos`
{
  `self.farmacos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

`FMDBDataAccess *db = [[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init];`

`self.farmacos = [db getFarmacos];`
}
`-(void) populateDescrip`
{
   `self.descript = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

`FMDBDataAccess *db = [[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init];`

`self.descript = [db getDescripcion];`
}

`- (void)viewDidUnload`
{
    `[super viewDidUnload];`
  }

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
{
   `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`
}

`- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`
{
    `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`
}

`- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`
{
   `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];`
}

`- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`
{
   `[super viewDidDisappear:animated];`
}

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    `return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);`
}

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`
{

```
// Return the number of sections.
```

`return 1;`
}

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
{

`self.copiaFarmaco = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel]text];
    NSLog(@"%@",copiaFarmaco);`
}
`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pasarDatos"]){`

```
    AddFarmacoViewController *segundoView = [segue destinationViewController];

    segundoView.nombre = self.copiaFarmaco;
}
```

}

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
{
   `return [self.farmacos count];`
}

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
{
   `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
  `if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
    }
 `Farmaco *farmaco = [farmacos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`

`[[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",farmaco.farmacoId]];
    return cell;`
}

@end

Comment: please provide your code to understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the segue from the First ViewController to second ViewController (Not from a Button to Second ViewController)

Inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToLocation" sender:the object you want to pass];
    }
```

then get the object here

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"segueToLocation"]) {    
         SecondViewController *dest = (SecondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
         //the sender is what you pass into the previous method
         dest.labelValue=sender
    }
}
```

Comment: In secondView make this:

 - (void) viewDidLoad{
titulo.text = nombre;
}

I think the problem is here becose the program get the title label right, and after retur to this method and titulo.text //is a label and nombre are nil.

Your anwer is right can help me in the final pass?

Comment: it might be that you are pushing the controller twice. This response is right tho. You might have a connection done in your storyboard from the tableView to push next VC on tap. In that case, remove it and do it in code like this response suggests .